# Blue lines in my .targets file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm following many blog/StackOv posts to make this. Still I get blue lines. And my vedlegg folder is deleted.

I'm using MSBuild for publishing from command line.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases you can safely ignore squiggly lines in MSBuild file. The XSD files that Visual Studio uses for MSBuild only support subset of MSBuild syntactical expressions. Most of the properties, groups and metadata for standard targets are reflected there, but not any custom build elements.

You can interpret the squigglies as anything that is outside of standard MSBuild properties and tasks. I also notices in many cases even standard tasks and properties are not present in XML schema for MSBuild files supplied by Microsoft, which is an obvious bug, but there is very little useful you can get from those XSD files anyway.